# How to add .env Variables on DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet

Tags: node.js, typescript, digital-ocean, droplet

I deployed my Node js app to DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet.

The app needs the variables in my .env file. How can I create those variables in DigitalOcean droplet please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you deploy your app to the Droplet?

You should be able to copy a `.env` file to the Droplet using the same mechanism that you copied the NodeJS files to the Droplet.

The simplest way to copy files securely is to use [`scp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

The syntax is:

```sh
scp \
-i /path/to/your/ssh_private_key \
path/to/your/.env \
root@[droplet-ip]:/path/to/your/app
```

> **NOTE** this will copy the `.env` file into your `app` directory.

If you are not using ssh keys with your Droplet (and you should), you can read [how to add ssh keys either to an existing or new Droplet](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/).

Comment: is it safer to put .env as it is in the droplet?